# Android not redrawing invalidated view on API 16

Tags: android, api, invalidation

I have implemented ZoomView on which I am drawing many items and when I click on one of them it changes it's view and calls invalidate. This works everywhere I tested (API 8, API 10, API 19) but it doesn't work on API 16.

On the API 16 the problem is that changed item is redraw only when I move with the screen in my ZoomView.

And to be more weird, even that all items are identical and have only different position some of them get redrawn when clicked and some doesn't. The items that works are the ones in top left corner which can be drawn on screen with scale 1 and translate [0,0].

Problem is probably with my ZoomView, here is simplified code:

```
public class ZoomView extends FrameLayout {
//SOME VARIABLES

public ZoomView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background));

    scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
    //COMPUTE TRANSLATION OR DETERMINE WHERE IT WAS CLICKED
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(posX, posY);
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    v.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        //COMPUTE SCALE AND CALL INVALIDATE
    }
}
}
```